# JavaScript for Firefox 35 and later

Tags: firefox, java, javascript, icedtea

Is there anything current or installing a Java and JavaScript for the new Firefox? I recently upgraded Firefox. Now websites I need are not working. There is old information about IcedTea Java plug-in and all kinds of long scripts. I am lost, and I don't know what I suddenly don't have.

Comment: Note that Java (of which Iced Tea is related to) is *completely* different to Javascript (which is built-into Firefox). Please [edit] your title and question to clarify which you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Icedtea Java Plugin is a web browser plugin to execute Java applets. You can install Icedtea Java Plugin from the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories (*icedtea-7-plugin*) and the default Ubuntu 16.04 and later  repositories (*icedtea-8-plugin*), and this will also install whatever Java dependency packages you need to install Icedtea Java Plugin.

JavaScript works in Firefox out of the box. To prove it try this [minPaint Demo](http://viliusle.github.io/miniPaint/) from Mozilla Demo Studio.

To run your own JavaScript code in Firefox 57 and later follow these steps:

1. Select *Settings* menu (3 horizontal lines icon **≡** in the upper right corner ) -> *Web Developer* -> *Scratchpad*.
2. Click the **Run** button on the Scratchpad toolbar to run your JavaScript code.

Example JavaScript code:

```
#!/usr/bin/js
var animal = "dog";
var count = 2;
console.log("The", animal, "ate", count, "biscuits.");
```

Results:

```
The dog ate 2 biscuits.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had problems too running Java applets with Iced Tea. I installed Oracle Java to solve the problem following the info on [this webpage](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

I installed  version 8:

open Terminal:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

update package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Oracle Java 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

While installation, you’ll be asked to agree the license and then the installer start downloading Java file from oracle website and install it on your system.

To set the default Java:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Finally check whether everyting is OK:

```
java -version
```